# Converting Polyline to Point Shapefile using arcgisscripting?

Tags: arcpy, point, line

I would like to convert the vertices of an existing Polyline-Shapefile into a Point Shapefile, but I have a problem with reading out the geometries of the polylines (getPart()).

```
    outpath = os.path.split(SHPInput)
    Temp_PointShp = gp.CreateFeatureclass(outpath[0],"SohlPoint_temp.shp", "POINT",None, "ENABLED", "ENABLED") # empty PointShapefile
    gp.addfield_management(Temp_PointShp, "Z_Value", "DOUBLE")
    gp.addfield_management(Temp_PointShp, "M_Value", "DOUBLE")


    Srows = gp.SearchCursor(SHPInput)   # Cursor 
    Irows = gp.InsertCursor(Temp_PointShp)

    row = Srows.next()
    while row: # for every row of the Polyline-Shapefile
        Geom = row.shape # Geometry     
        OArray = Geom.getPart() # Array with Array

        PArray = OArray.getPart(0) # Array with Points


        Points = OArray.next()
        while Points: # for all vertices...

            row = Irows.NewRow() # create new row in Point-Shapefile


            row.X = Points.X
            row.Y = Points.Y
            row.Z = Points.Z
            row.M = Points.M
            Irows.InsertRow(row)

            Points = PArray.next()


        row = Srows.next()
```

Comment: What version and license level of ArcGIS Desktop are you using?  What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Feature Vertices to Points" tool, which will convert all vertices of the polyline into points. There are a number of "Point Type" options, which you can find out more about here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm

In order to get the coordinates of your points, you can add a lat and long field within your new point shapefile and calculate geometry. Go to the attribute table > add fields > lat/long > right click the field > calculate geometry. Here, Lat = Y coordinate of point, and Long = X coordinate of point.

Using arcpy you might use:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"path/to/workspace"

polyline = r"path/to/polyline"
polyline_vertices = arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(polyline, "polyline_vertices", "ALL")

latfield = arcpy.AddField_management(polyline_vertices, "Lat", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(polyline_vertices, "Lat", "!Shape.Centroid.X!", "PYTHON_9.3")

longfield = arcpy.AddField_management(polyline_vertices, "Long", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(polyline_vertices, "Long", "!Shape.Centroid.Y!", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Feature%20Vertices%20to%20Points%20(Data%20Management) suggests that the license level being used by the asker may affect whether this will provide a solution.

Comment: True. Lets see what the OP comes back with re: Desktop version and license.